# Cannot assign ctypes Structure to numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to assign a custom `ctypes.Structure` into a numpy array as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

class Struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ctypes.c_int32),
        ("y", ctypes.c_int32),
    ]

array = np.zeros((2,), dtype=Struct)
array[0] = Struct(2,2)
```

But I get error message:

```
    array[0] = Struct(2, 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```

Is there anyway to assign ctypes structs to a numpy array?